# Getting a syntax error for except in python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.5

I have a function to ask the user to input an integer and I am trying to put in a try function that will replace ValueError with "Input must be an integer." but I keep getting a syntax error for my except! I am using Python 3.5.2

```
def get_int ():
    s = int(input("Give me an integer: "))
    return(s)

while s is float:
    try:
        s = int(input("Give me an integer: "))
        except(ValueError) as "Input must be an integer."
        print("Input must be an integer.")

except ValueError as:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing the except line to `except ValueError:` without the "as string" part

Answer (score 1):

`except` should be at the same indentation level as `try`, needs a colon before the body, and the `as` clause is used to hold the error in a variable; something like this:

```
    try:
        s = int(input("Give me an integer: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be an integer.")
```